# Ubuntu 20.04 won't start after lid closes and opens

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, nvidia

I dual-booted my system with Ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10, I have my windows in disk C (SSD) and Ubuntu in separate hard disk space (HDD). Every time I close the lid of my laptop and open it, the screen went black with a white underscore blinking, and then I have to hard reboot it. This problem only happens in Ubuntu and not in Windows.

**System specifications** 
Laptop model:- Acer predator Helios 300
Memory:- 128GB SSD, 1TB HDD
Graphics:- NVIDIA 1050 ti
Ram:- 8GB

Comment: Sounds like a powersavings issue,   on most boxes wake from functionality is part of the firmware (bios) and your Linux isn't configured or picking up on it.

Comment: What nvidia drivers (if any do you have installed)?